# How to change text file variable dynamically from database(mdb/sql server)

Tags: java, database, parsing, text-parsing

How to change text file variable dynamically from database(mdb/sql server).

I have text file in my java Project in Particular format
like:

```
|GET|/gfas/proposals/${CDB_SID0}|200||jsonbody.proposals[0].text==ClientCDB|
```

`ClientCDB` is variable.

I want to Retrieve `ClientCDB` value from database dynamically at runtime.

Please help me on this.

Comment: so you want to retrieve `ClientCDB` value from db right

Comment: @Satya yes right, actually this code belongs to fitness tool, and dynamically i want to update data from my MDb file for different-2 test cases

Comment: update means you want to put some other variable in place of `ClientCDB`. give input=? and output=?

Comment: Yes kind of, or we can have database result set as out, but at run-time only